Get a list of ORM objects without duplicates of a specific attribute
Good afternoon, please tell me how to get an array of records in SQLAlchemy so that a certain field does not repeat itself. Let's say I have existing users:
User(email='email1@gmail.com', name='Mike')
User(email='email2@gmail.com', name='Bob')
User(email='email2@gmail.com', name='John')
I need to get a list of users where the email is not repeated, for example
[User mike, User bob]
How might I accomplish that?

Which RDBMS are you using?

I use MySQL v8.0

Yeah, that was error by me, I wanna to add at least one model with repeating email. The result should show me how to get users without duplicated emails

Probably the most straightforward approach would be to

create a subquery that retrieves the PK values for distinct values of the "unique" attribute using MIN() and GROUP BY, and then
use that subquery in the IN clause of the main query

with Session(engine) as sess:
    id_list = select(func.min(User.id)).group_by(User.email)
    results = sess.scalars(select(User).where(User.id.in_(id_list))).all()
    pprint(results)
    """
    [User(id=1, name='Mike', email='email1@gmail.com'),
     User(id=2, name='Bob', email='email2@gmail.com')]
    """

